# Ansible loop to create docker networks

Tags: docker-compose, ansible, jinja2

Suppose I have my docker networks defined in a variable such as:

```
docker_networks:
  - name: default
    driver: bridge
  - name: proxy
    driver: bridge
    ipam_options:
      subnet: '192.168.100.0/24'
  - name: socket_proxy
    driver: bridge
    ipam_options:
      subnet: '192.168.101.0/24'
```

How would I go about running this with a loop to create these docker networks?

I tried the following, however the ipam_config parameter causes it to fail if no subnet is defined:

```
- name: Create networks
  docker_network:
    name: '{{ item.name }}'
    driver: '{{ item.driver | default(omit) }}'
    ipam_config:
      - subnet: '{{ item.ipam_options.subnet | default(omit) }}'
  loop: '{{ docker_networks }}'
```

Comment: It looks like you could simply omit the `default` network from your `docker_networks` variable; that's the only one that doesn't have a ` subnet` key, and you shouldn't need to create it because Docker has already created the `default` network for you.

Comment: I would if I could, this was just a simplified example though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify your `docker_networks` variable so that the value of the `ipam_options` key is a list of dictionaries:

```
docker_networks:
  - name: proxy
    driver: bridge
    ipam_options:
      - subnet: '192.168.100.0/24'
  - name: socket_proxy
    driver: bridge
    ipam_options:
      - subnet: '192.168.101.0/24'
  - name: no_subnet
    driver: bridge
```

Then you can rewrite your task like this:

```
- name: Create networks
  community.docker.docker_network:
    name: '{{ item.name }}'
    driver: '{{ item.driver | default(omit) }}'
    ipam_config: "{{ item.ipam_options | default(omit) }}"
  loop: '{{ docker_networks }}'
```

(I would also just rename the `ipam_options` key to `ipam_config`, so
that it matches the parameter name.)

Comment: Note that I've removed the `default` network here, because on my system attempting to modify the `default` network results in an error.